# How to move multiple buttons to the top right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have 10 buttons and I would like to place the buttons on the top right, but I don't know how to do it? Currently my buttons are at the bottom, I don't know how to move my buttons?

I would like to get this result, (see below)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8hki.png)

I think I need to use a `display:flex` ?

Do you have any idea, please?

Here is my code below

Thank you in advance for your help et your time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
   </head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <body>
      <div class="home-content container">
         <h1 class="text-center pt-5 pb-3">Signalétique</h1>
         <div class="row pt-3 container">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <table class="table table-hover table-striped" style="width: 60%">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Ticker</th>
                           <td>SOLB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Code SVM</th>
                           <td>347075</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Code ISIN</th>
                           <td>BE00003470755</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Genre</th>
                           <td>Actions</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Pays d'origine</th>
                           <td>Belgique</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Secteur économique</th>
                           <td>Matériaux</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Devise de cotation</th>
                           <td>EUR</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Groupe de cotation</th>
                           <td>(AO)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Unité de cotation</th>
                           <td>1,0000000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Site Internet</th>
                           <td>www.solvay.com</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ">Best Execution</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Etat du marché</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Graphiques Historiques</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Historique des cours</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Ordre</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">Best Execution</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">Etat du marché</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">Graphiques Historiques</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">Historique des cours</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">Ordre</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor adjustments will need to be made to the columns, but here's a solution:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<body>
  <div class="home-content container">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-5 pb-3">Signalétique</h1>
    <div class="row pt-3 container">
      <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <table class="table table-hover table-striped" style="width: 60%;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Ticker</th>
                    <td>SOLB</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Code SVM</th>
                    <td>347075</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Code ISIN</th>
                    <td>BE00003470755</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <td>Actions</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Pays d'origine</th>
                    <td>Belgique</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Secteur économique</th>
                    <td>Matériaux</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Devise de cotation</th>
                    <td>EUR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Groupe de cotation</th>
                    <td>(AO)</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Unité de cotation</th>
                    <td>1,0000000</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Site Internet</th>
                    <td>www.solvay.com</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                    Best Execution
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                    Etat du marché
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                    Graphiques Historiques
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                    Historique des cours
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                    Ordre
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">
                    Best Execution
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">
                    Etat du marché
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">
                    Graphiques Historiques
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">
                    Historique des cours
                  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ms-2">
                    Ordre
                  </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a flexbox 
First use main container then display it as flex and with some container and items properties you will get what you want
Display : flex
And proceed ....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).